# The order of MSBuild build Events in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: xml, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

According to this [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/understanding-custom-build-steps-and-build-events?view=msvc-160), for each project in a Visual Studio 2019 solution, build events run in the following order with other build steps (including custom build steps and tools):

- **Pre-Build event**
- Custom build tools on individual files
- MIDL
- Resource compiler
- The C/C++ compiler
- **Pre-Link event**
- Linker or Librarian (as appropriate)
- Manifest Tool
- BSCMake
- Custom build step on the project
- **Post-Build event**

*The custom build step on the project and a post-build event run sequentially after all other build processes finish.*

However, when the WDK v10.0.19041.0 is installed, the `StampInf` and `InfVerif` are executed **before** the `Pre-Build Event`.

This is evidenced by the following Microsoft's code:

```
<Target Name="StampInf"
          Condition="'@(Inf)' != ''"
          BeforeTargets="InfVerif">
```

...

```
<Target Name="InfVerif"
          Condition="'@(Inf)' != '' and '$(IsDriverAppToolset)' != 'true'"
          AfterTargets="StampInf"
          BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
```

The Microsoft's code above is excerpted from: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.Common.targets`

Notice, how the `AfterTargets` and `BeforeTargets` directives establish the order of execution  of `StampInf`, `InfVerify` and `PreBuildEvent`.

**Question 1**: Is  the execution of `StampInf` and `InfVerify` **before** the `Pre-Build Event` a bug in implementation or an error in Microsoft's documentation ?
**Question 2**: How to execute a custom command before `InfVerif` in a portable manner (without modifying Microsoft's source files of the Visual Studio or the WDK) ?

Comment: What's the bug means in your question1? Do you mean StampInf and InfVerify are not included in the list in the documentation? Do you want [to define where in the build the custom build step will execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-add-a-custom-build-step-to-msbuild-projects?view=msvc-160#to-define-where-in-the-build-the-custom-build-step-will-execute).

Comment: The bug is the `Pre-Build Event`. executing **after** the  `StampInf` and `InfVerify` tools.

Comment: You can create an issue on [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report) or click the github link at the bottom of [the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/understanding-custom-build-steps-and-build-events?view=msvc-160) to report a documentation problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug that `InfVerif` is implemented to explicitly reference being before the `PreBuildEvent` target. The WDK shouldn't be interfering with the semantics of `PreBuildEvent`.

However, MSBuild will ignore a reference to a target that doesn't exist in the current project. You can set your target to be `BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent;InfVerif;StampInf"` and for projects that don't have an `InfVerif` or `StampInf` target there should not be an error. You don't need to modify Microsoft's MSBuild code to get around this issue.