# Regex to match comments in an INF file

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

While designing a Regex to match comments in an INF file ( its formal syntax definition is [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/general-syntax-rules-for-inf-files#-line-format-continuation-and-comments) ), I came across an insurmountable (to me) problem where a mismatch is occurring when an opening left square bracket is wrongly paired with a double quote (dquote).

Here is a brief description of the comment syntax in the INF file:

> Note ; A comment starts with a semicolon and continues untill the EOL
> A string begins with an odd dquote "and terminates at the next dquote" ...or at the EOL. 
> Unbalanced dquotes "are implicitly closed by the EOL .i.e. ;this is not a comment.
> A semicolon ";inside a string" loses its power to initiate a comment.
> ...however, an even number of dquotes "" before the semicolon ;does not disable its power to
> initiate a comment
> A string can contain a dquote when such dquote is escaped with another dquote, in other words - "doubled dquote""."
> Inside a string "the semicolon ; a backslash \ and square brackets ][ are treated just like regular characters"
>
> ;From the comment-initiating semicolon to the EOL, the other semicolons; the line continuation backslash, the dquotes """ and square brackets ][ are treated just like regular characters. \
>
> A semicolon [inside;] square brackets does not initiate a comment; but outside - it does.
> A left square bracket [ before the semicolon ; disables its comment initiating function; too.
> Neither nested nor unbalanced square brackets occur in the input unless they are inside a string.
>
> The line continuation sequence (backslash+newline) does not work:
>
> - inside ;comments\
> - between the left square bracket `[` and EOL \
> - between an unbalanced dquote and EOL "\
> - between balanced dquotes"\ 
>   ;nice try"
>
> ( unbalanced and nested square brackets do not occur in the input unless they are inside a string )

Here is my c# (.NET flavor) Regex to match the comments:

```
(?:^|(?<=\n))(?>(?:[^;""\[\n]*[""\[][^""\]\n]*[""\]])*)(?>[^;""\[\n;]*)(;.*?)(?:\n|$)
```

See its **[simulation here](https://regex101.com/r/qwM9oz/1)** (click "List" in the left panel) to get a list of matches.

From the text of the syntax description above, my Regex pattern generates the following matches denoted in green color:

[image: Matches in green]

However my Regex fails with the following input:

> A semicolon [inside";] square brackets" does not initiate a comment; but outside - it does.

The expected match is at the second semicolon, but it matches at the first semicolon because the left square bracket is wrongly paired to the first dquote.

QUESTION: How to repair this Regex so only a right square bracket can pair&close a left square bracket ?

Comment: Why regex? Why not use an INI parser?

Comment: While there might be a solution to your problem... the next problem will be: what about nested brackets (`[[;]]`)? An what about `[[][[;]]]`? You will have to maintain a state for each opening bracket. You *normally* don't solve this with pure regex anymore, you will utilize a language parser instead.

Comment: @stackprotector: I quote: "*Neither nested nor unbalanced square brackets occur in the input unless they are inside a string.*"

Comment: @ gunr2171: I have never heard of INI parser that would be applicable to an INF file syntax and that would allow me to replace these comments with their refactored versions and accessible from this environment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-inline-tasks?view=vs-2019

Comment: @PavelStepanek They might not occur in a correct input. But the determination of correctness is part of the parsing process, I assume.

Comment: @stackprotector::  The VS Environment has a separate process called `InfVerif` that disallows illegal syntax. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74480853/the-order-of-msbuild-build-events-in-visual-studio-2019

Comment: Anyway, because nested brackets are illegal in the INF syntax, they do not need to be treated like nested entities.  One-level treatment is sufficient. When dquotes inside dquotes occur, they are not treated as nested tokens, either.